# Print custom object in rmarkdown and knitr (PDF and HTML)

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

Let's say I have a package with a function that returns an S3 object:

```r
new_myclass <- function() {
  return(structure(list(a=1, b=2), class = "myclass"))
}
```

I also have two functions that take a `myclass` object and return respectively a HTML representation and a LaTeX representation of the object.

```
myclass2html <- function(obj) { return("<p>MyClass object</p>")}
myclass2latex <- function(obj) { return("\begin{em}MyClass\end{em} object $x$")}
```

What functions/methods should I define to provide consistent and transparent `knitr` and `rmarkdown` support? I would like to support both `.Rmd` files and `.R` files with a header like:

```
#'---
#' title: My document
#' output: pdf_output
#'---
```

So far my approach goes through the `knit_print` method:

```
knit_print.myclass <- function(x, ...) {
  rmarkdown_fmt <- rmarkdown::metadata$output
  knitr_fmt <- knitr::opts_knit$get("out.format")
  # should I use these heuristics with both variables?
  if (rmarkdownfmt == "pdf_document") {
    return(knitr::asis_output(myclass2latex(x)))
  }
  if (knitr_fmt %in% c("html", "markdown")) {
    return(knitr::asis_output(myclass2html(x)))
  } else {
    stop("Format not supported!")
  }
}
```

My main issue is that there may be two variables `rmarkdown::metadata$output` and `knitr::opts_knit$get("out.format")` that may or may not be defined (depending on whether or not `rmarkdown` is being used). I find this confusing.

- Is `knit_print` the right method to customize for this purpose?
- What is the right way to know the output format? Is there a `get_output_format` function that tells me the output format?

To put the question in context, I am working on the [condformat](http://www.sergioller.com/2016-03-10-condformat-release.md) package that allows to visualize DataFrames with conditional formatting rules.

EDIT: So far I have been doing my own voodoo to detect the output format:

```
#' @importFrom rmarkdown metadata
#' @importFrom knitr opts_knit
guess_output_format <- function() {
  rmd_output <- tryCatch({rmarkdown::metadata$output},
                         error = function(e) {NULL})
  if (is.null(rmd_output)) {
    rmd_output = ""
  }
  if (is.list(rmd_output)) {
    rmd_output <- names(rmd_output)[1]
  }
  if (rmd_output == "pdf_document") {
    return("latex")
  } else if (rmd_output %in% c("html_document", "html_vignette")) {
    return("html")
  } else if (rmd_output != "") {
    stop("Unsupported rmarkdown output format:", rmd_output)
  }
  # No rmarkdown, let's try with knitr:
  format <- knitr::opts_knit$get("out.format")
  if (format %in% c("html", "markdown")) {
    return("html")
  } else if (format %in% c("latex")) {
    return("latex")
  } else {
    stop("Format not supported!")
  }
}
```

**EDIT**: Further discussion here: https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/649

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With knitr 1.18 this is much simpler:

```
guess_output_format <- function() {
  if (knitr::is_html_output()) {
    return("html")
  } else if (knitr::is_latex_output()) {
    return("latex")
  } else {
    return("unsupported")
 }
}
```

Related issue: https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/649